# Problems interfacing an hd44780-based LCD with a P89LPC9351-based microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, lcd, sdcc, hd44780

I can't manage to get my LCD to initialize, am i doing something wrong? Any help appreciated!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <p89lpc9351.h>

    #define XTAL 7373000L
    #define BAUD 115600L

    #define LCD_data P2
    #define LCD_rs   P1_4
    #define LCD_rw   P1_6
    #define LCD_en   P1_7

    void putchar (char c)
    {
        while (!TI);
        TI=0;

        SBUF=c;
    }

    char getchar (void)
    {
        while (!RI);
        RI=0;
        return SBUF;
    }

    void InitSerialPort(void)
    {
        BRGCON=0x00;                    //Make sure the baud rate generator is off
        BRGR1=((XTAL/BAUD)-16)/0x100;
        BRGR0=((XTAL/BAUD)-16)%0x100;
        BRGCON=0x03;                    //Turn-on the baud rate generator
        SCON=0x52;                      //Serial port in mode 1, ren, txrdy, rxempty
        P1M1=0x00;                      //Enable pins RxD and Txd
        P1M2=0x00;                      //Enable pins RxD and Txd
    }

    void delay_ms(long ms)
    {
        long i;

        while (ms--)
            for (i=0; i < 330; i++)
                ;
    }

    void command(char i)
    {
        LCD_data = i;                   //put data on output Port
        LCD_rs =0;                      //D/I=LOW : send instruction
        LCD_rw =0;                      //R/W=LOW : Write
        LCD_en = 1;
        delay_ms(1);                    //enable pulse width >= 300ns
        LCD_en = 0;
    }

    void write(char i)
    {
        LCD_data = i;                   //put data on output Port
        LCD_rs =1;                      //D/I=LOW : send data
        LCD_rw =0;                      //R/W=LOW : Write
        LCD_en = 1;
        delay_ms(1);                    //enable pulse width >= 300ns
        LCD_en = 0;                     //Clock enable: falling edge
    }

    void LCD_init()
    {
        LCD_en  = 0;
        delay_ms(100);                  //Wait >15 msec after power is applied
        command(0x30);                  //command 0x30 = Wake up
        delay_ms(30);                   //must wait 5ms, busy flag not available
        command(0x30);                  //command 0x30 = Wake up #2
        delay_ms(10);                   //must wait 160us, busy flag not available
        command(0x30);                  //command 0x30 = Wake up #3
        delay_ms(10);                   //must wait 160us, busy flag not available
        command(0x38);                  //Function set: 8-bit/2-line
        command(0x10);                  //Set cursor
        command(0x0c);                  //Display ON; Cursor ON
        command(0x06);                  //Entry mode set 
    }

    void main (void)
    {
        InitSerialPort();
        LCD_init();
    }
```

Comment: You might also try asking this over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ because more hardware oriented folk hang out there. I don't think this is an off-topic question here, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The init sequence looks ok.  Did you forget to explicitly set P2 and P1 pins to outputs?